# Find a list of unique IP address from a text file

Tags: java, regex, parsing, text

How to write a program in Java to find a list of unique IP address from a text file?

I am only a newbie at Java. And I have the following data in txt format:

```
Date first seen          Duration Proto      Source IP Addr:Port     Destination IP Addr:Port   Packets    Bytes Flows
2013-03-03 23:54:46.574     8.000 UDP      108.169.77.76:12345 ->    108.169.0.112:53           5      325     1
2013-03-03 23:59:51.984     0.000 UDP     100.253.69.196:62458 ->  100.256.234.129:1947         1       68     1
2013-03-03 23:59:52.048     0.000 UDP      108.450.45.35:123124 ->    108.123.0.987:9101        2     1686     1
```

Please note that I just made up those IP address and the actual data set is much larger.

I would like to know how can I write a program in java to find a list of unique source / destination IP address ? And also to count the number of occurrences of each IP addresses in the text file as a source /destination address ?

Answer (score 4):

This is what the Set collection is for.  Create a class that holds all the data of one row, implement its `equals` and `hashcode` method so that it only cares about source and destination, and then simply by adding all the classes to the Set, you'll have unique results in the end.

Comment: @Kaz "I would like to know how can I write a program in **java**"

Comment: I would like to ask how could you split the columns such that I obtain a list of source IP address and a list of Destination address?

Comment: @user1769197 You can iterate the Set.  For each iteration, you add the source into one list and add the destination to another.  After your iteration ends, you'll have two populated lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of IP's, I would suggest you to convert them into long:

```
public long ipConversion(String addr){
    String[] addrArray = addr.split("\\."); 

    long num = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < addrArray.length; i++) { 
        int power = 3 - i;

        num += ((Integer.parseInt(addrArray[i]) % 256 * Math.pow(256, power))); 
    } 
    return num; 
}
```

Then, you can add unique ones into an arrayList, which is for `n` element `O(n*log_n)`

```
ArrayList<Long> arr = new ArrayList<>();
int x = Collections.binarySearch(arr, IPaddress);
if(x < 0)//this mean IPaddress doesnt exist in your list
    arr.add(-x-1, IPaddress)
//binary search return -insertionpoint if the element was in the arraylist
//so you should insert it to -insertionpoint-1.
```

Then convert unique ips into IPaddress format.

Alternatively, cou can override comparable interface which compares two IPs, and you can do binarysearch using that. So you wouldnt have to do conversions, which would be faster.